How to Match ASS Subtitle Font Size with Flutter Text Size for a 1080p Video?
I’m working on a project where I need to synchronize the font size of ASS subtitles with the text size a user sees in a Flutter application. The goal is to ensure that the text size in a 1080p video matches what the user sees in the app.
What I've Tried:

Calculating font size using height ratio (PlayResY/DeviceHeight):


I used the formula:

FontSize_ASS = FontSize_Flutter * (PlayResY / DeviceHeight)


While the result seemed logical, the final output in the video was smaller than expected.


Adding a scaling factor:


I introduced a scaling factor (around 3.0) to address the size discrepancy.
This improved the result but still felt inconsistent and lacked precision.


Using force_style in FFmpeg:


I applied the force_style parameter to control the font size in FFmpeg directly.

ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "subtitles=subtitle.ass:force_style='FontSize=90'" -c:a copy output.mp4


While it produced better results, it’s not an ideal solution as it bypasses the calculations in the ASS file.


Aligning PlayResX and PlayResY in the ASS file:
I ensured that these parameters matched the target video resolution (1920×1080):

PlayResX: 1920
PlayResY: 1080


Despite this adjustment, the font size didn’t align perfectly with the Flutter app text size.


Reading font metrics from the font file dynamically:
To improve precision, I wrote a function in Flutter that reads font metrics (units per EM, ascender, and descender) from the TTF font file and calculates a more accurate scaling factor:

Future<double?> readFontMetrics(
      String fontFilePath, 
      double originalFontSize,
) async {
  final fontData = await File(fontFilePath).readAsBytes();
  final fontBytes = fontData.buffer.asUint8List();
  final byteData = ByteData.sublistView(fontBytes);

  int numTables = readUInt16BE(byteData, 4);
  int offsetTableStart = 12;
  Map<String, Map<String, int>> tables = {};

  for (int i = 0; i < numTables; i++) {
    int recordOffset = offsetTableStart + i * 16;
    String tag =
        utf8.decode(fontBytes.sublist(recordOffset, recordOffset          + 4));
    int offset = readUInt32BE(byteData, recordOffset + 8);
    int length = readUInt32BE(byteData, recordOffset + 12);

    tables[tag] = {
      'offset': offset,
      'length': length,
    };
  }

  if (!tables.containsKey('head') || !tables.containsKey('hhea'){
    print('Required tables not found in the font file.');
    return null;
  }

  int headOffset = tables['head']!['offset']!;
  int unitsPerEm = readUInt16BE(byteData, headOffset + 18);

  int hheaOffset = tables['hhea']!['offset']!;
  int ascender = readInt16BE(byteData, hheaOffset + 4);
  int descender = readInt16BE(byteData, hheaOffset + 6);

  print('unitsPerEm: $unitsPerEm');
  print('ascender: $ascender');
  print('descender: $descender');

  int nominalSize = unitsPerEm;
  int realDimensionSize = ascender - descender;
  double scaleFactor = realDimensionSize / nominalSize;
  double realFontSize = originalFontSize * scaleFactor;

  print('Scale Factor: $scaleFactor');
  print('Real Font Size: $realFontSize');

  return realFontSize;
}


This function dynamically reads the font properties (ascender, descender, and unitsPerEM) and calculates a scale factor to get the real font size. Despite this effort, discrepancies persist when mapping it to the ASS font size.

Question:
How can I ensure that the font size in the ASS file accurately reflects the size the user sees in Flutter? Is there a reliable method to calculate or align the sizes correctly across both systems? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you! 

I didn't use Flutter a single time, so I don't know much about it, but according to here font size in Flutter is specified as in units per EM, while ASS font size is based on real dimensions for scaling.
I described how to convert between those in this post.

I’ve tested this approach, but the resulting font size still doesn’t match what the user sees on their mobile device. I’ll share the method I wrote in Flutter in a post. I’d greatly appreciate it if you could let me know where I might have made a mistake.

I can't really test it myself in Flutter, so really can't help. Your best shot is to actually check how FreeType and Harfbuzz works in Skia (Flutter's renderer) and compare it to how Libass handle it.
Check: Skia FreeType, Libass, Libass logic reimplementation in Moonscript
Why do you match it? Why do you need to do it, maybe there is other way?
